# Debug-iphonesimulator gtmsessionfetcher.framework swift no such file directory

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, fbsdk, gtm-oauth2

I'm fairly new to programming. I am trying to install Firebase and the Facebook iOS SDK into my app to allow for Facebook authentication. I have already installed the necessary pod files(FireBase) and Frameworks (FBSDK) on to my project. I am trying to build the app now but I come across the following error.

> /Users/JuanPa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jps-showcase-dytvwqtvwsggladxlmwwyoflurwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/jps-showcase.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework: No such file or directory

I have already tried:

1. Updating my Cocoapod
2. Updating the Firebase Pods
3. Deleting my .xcworkspace and creating it again
4. Deleting my derived data

And some other things, but those are the main ones, and nothing has worked. I guess it really comes down to the `GTMSessionFetcher.framework` not being found? I searched into my Project's Pods directories and found the GTMSSessionFetcher > Source > and found the files in the picture below.

Pods directory:

[image: Pods directory]

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. After an entire day of dealing with this, I ended up just restarting my project from scratch but in the process I found some things that I may have done wrong which may have led to my issue.

**Possible errors were -**

1. I had changed the bundle i.d after I had already built the app.
2. I created a Framework file within the project name folder but not directly under the entire project, perhaps this is why it could not find the *...Debug-iphonesimulator/jps-showcase.app/Frameworks/....*

**3. Did not include the FBSDK folder path in my Project > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths.**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was because I was using the Facebook Swift SDK and I forgot to uncomment the

```
use_frameworks!
```

statement in my Podfile.