# Swift iOS GoogleAPIClientForREST – Shell Script Invocation Error GTMSessionFetcher.framework: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-api

I'm programming a Swift iOS app in XCode 9.2 (Dated, I know), and I've tried to integrate GoogleAPIClientForREST using Cocoapods. When you integrate GoogleAPIClientForREST (and possibly other pods, I don't know), it also downloads GTMSessionFetcher. Since the integration of the pods, the app won't run and gives this Shell Script Invocation Error:

**/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Teachers_Assistant-aphjxihtqtmedabcymmxjlmxduzc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Teachers Assistant.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework: No such file or directory**

However, I can't open *Teachers Assistant.app,* as it's not a folder. *GTMSessionFetcher.framework* exists, but inside of the folder circled in **red** in the image at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkm7s.png), not inside the .app file circled in **blue**.

I've tried the suggestions at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474586/debug-iphonesimulator-gtmsessionfetcher-framework-swift-no-such-file-directory), the suggestions in the question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144124/gtmsessionfetcher-framework-no-such-file-or-directory), this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323326/ld-framework-not-found-gtmsessionfetcher-after-pod-install/40592635), this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434184/ios-swift-no-such-file-or-directory-in-debug-iphoneos), and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474586/debug-iphonesimulator-gtmsessionfetcher-framework-swift-no-such-file-directory). None of them have worked, though if you think that there was something I did wrong while trying to carry out those steps feel free to tell me.

All of my code is online at this [repo](https://github.com/therealFIGBERT/Teacher-s-Assistant), including the podfile. Thanks for the help!

**Additional information:** I plan on using the Google API to automate Sheets as a sort of storage information system to log attendance data and other miscellaneous information, if that helps at all.

Comment: "However, I can't open Teachers Assistant.app, as it's not a folder"  It's a package, and it is a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project's name should not contain special characters like `'` or space, this could create some problems when Cocoapods try to link the libraries. I suggest you to change your project's name to TeachersAssistance (it worked for me). Here is the suggested steps:

1. Change project's name in the navigator. Xcode will recommend you to refractor the project, accept it:
   [image]
2. Update podfile to point to new targets's names
3. Cocoapods will create a new workspace TeachersAssistance. Use it and delete the old one.
4. Remove Pods_Teacher__Assistance from new workspace. From now it will use Pods_TeachersAssistant.
5. Compile again and enjoy your project :)

Comment: I've followed all of your steps, but I've hit a snag on 3. I changed the `target` line to `target 'TeachersAssistant' do` (I renamed the project to TeachersAssistant), but it didn't create a new workspace. How do I get the pod to create a new workspace? @qtngo

Comment: @FIGBERT: you must do `pod install` again so Cocoapods create the new workspace for you